# onclick event works only on first product it doesn't work on other fetched data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing shopping cart in codeigniter where I am fetching data from data base and when user clicks on add to cart the the data related to current item which is clicked by user get store in jQuery variables now I am facing problem that onclick event works only on first fetched item and on the rest it won't works and I am confuse why it's not working. 
Here is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-9" >
        <?php if(isset($products))
        {
            foreach($products as $row)
            {
            ?>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-4" id="con">
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="products/<?=$row->sub_c_id?>/<?=$row->pid?>">
                    <img  id="imgslct" alt="<?=$row->pname?>" height="173" width="144" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$row->product_pic?>">                                       
                    </a>
                    <div class="name">
                    <a href="#" id="pname"><?=$row->pname?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">
                    <p id="price">price : <?=$row->pprice?></p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="pquan" value="<?=$row->pquantity;?>">
                    <button id="addtocart" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <?php 
            }
            } ?>
```

Here is JQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0;
       $("#con").on('click',function(){
           counter++;
           var pic=$(this).find("img").attr('src');
           alert(pic);
           var imgdata= $(this).find("#pname").text();

           var productquantity= $('#pquan').val(); 
           var productid=$('#pid').text(); 
           var price=$("#price").text(); 
           var qty="1";
           var session_id="<?=$this->session->userdata('session_id');?>";
           var pid="1";
            $("#counter").text(counter);
         var counting= $("#counter").text(counter);
           <?php $counting=''?>+counting;
           alert(counting);
           <?php $new_data=array('counter' => $counting ) ?>
           if(qty=="")
           {
            alert("no quantity added");
            return false;
           }

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"<?=base_url();?>temp_upload",
        data:"pic="+pic+"&imgdata="+imgdata+"&productquantity="+productquantity+"&productid="+productid+"&price="+price+"&qty="+qty+"&session_id="+session_id+"&pid="+pid,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);

            $("#uploaded").html();
        }
        });     


           $("#newdata").append('<tr><td class="image"><img alt="IMAGE" class="img-responsive" src="'+pic+'"></td><td class="name"><a href="project.html">Black Dress</a></td><td class="quantity">x&nbsp;3</td><td class="total">'+price+'</td><td class="remove"><img src="'+pic+'" alt="Remove" title="Remove"></td></tr>');
           });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Look into delegated events in jQuery since you're dynamically adding elements.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Doesn't seem so - he uses PHP to render all the rows, but has duplicate ID in every row.

Comment: @Shomz yes I get that, all your answers highlight that point.  But incase he wanted to attach events to the `remove` element he's adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are within a loop that is using the same `id` over and over with `id="con"` being the first.  Since ids must be unique within the DOM, you need to change them from an id to a class.

You should do something like:

```
<div class="col-md-4 con">
    <div class="product">
        <a href="products/<?=$row->sub_c_id?>/<?=$row->pid?>">
            <img class="imgslct" alt="<?=$row->pname?>" height="173" width="144" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$row->product_pic?>">                                       
        </a>
        <div class="name">
            <a href="#" class="pname"><?=$row->pname?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <p>price : <?=$row->pprice?></p>
            <input type="hidden" class="pquan" value="<?=$row->pquantity;?>">
            <button class="addtocart btn btn-lg btn-default">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change the beginning of your JavaScript to:

```
$(".con").on('click', function () 
{
    counter++;

    var $this = $(this);
    var pic = $this.find("img").attr('src');
    var imgdata = $this.find(".pname").text();
    var productquantity = $this.find('.pquan').val();
    var productid = $this.find('.pid').text();
    var price = $this.find(".price").text();
    var qty = "1";
    var session_id = "<?=$this->session->userdata('session_id');?>";
    var pid = "1";
```

Comment: @Vicky - you have other id's that need to change within the loop.  You can't have any static id within that loop. Change them all to classes.

Comment: @Vicky - Yup, `pname`, `pquan`, `pid`, `price`, `addtocart`.  They all need to change from `id` to `class` unless you can make them unique.

Comment: why you are using multiple class attributes ,it will not work 
<div class="col-md-4" class="con"> use
<div class="col-md-4 con">

Comment: you are more than welcome and this was the mistake thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

IDs should be unique.

The moment you change the id to a class (`#con` -> `.con`) and modify your code appropriatelly, they all will be selected.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/38PB2/

Comment: it didn't work and also the first item which was working has stop working

Comment: Yes, that's why I said `and modify your code appropriatelly`. You probably missed changing it somewhere. If you wish, you can paste your new code here.

Comment: now it start working but now I am facing another problem that I clicked on every product it add the data of the first product

Comment: I see, it's because all repeating IDs should either be converted to classes, or made unique in some way, like adding an index to each (like `#pname1`, `#pname1`, etc... for example, but I'd still stick to classes). Switching only `con` is not enough, because you have plenty of IDs that are repeating, thus only the first one of each getting triggered. If you can't pull it off, I'll write you the whole code.

Comment: Thanks a lot shomz  for this act of kindness but I will try to rewrite the whole script from beginning and with proper way and it will work for sure but you have cleared my concept therefore I am accepting your answer

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help! So, when there are unique items, use IDs, when there are many, use classes.

Comment: yea I will because of this I have lost my precious time

Comment: dude I have to un accept because there were another good and briefed answer there that point out my mistake and help me out with this code I appreciate your efforts but I have to vote up for the right

Answer (score 0):

first change the event to be attached to class not to id as id must be unique ,if you attach click event to id ,only the first element with that id will trigger that event

change

```
 <div class="col-md-4" id="con">
```

to

```
 <div class="col-md-4 con" >
```

also you have link tag inside that div which will make some problems till to stop propagation of that event

then to add click event to fetched elements you can use

```
  $(document).on('click','.con',function(){
  /// your code
  });
```

so click event will be attached to the new elements too